# Problema no código Jquery

Tags: javascript

Olá, pessoal. Estou fazendo o seguinte:
Um sistema onde o usuário pode embaralhar a ordem das imagens.

Clica no botão e randomicamente elas mudam de lugar.

Até ai tudo bem, o problema é que quando eu pego o retorno e jogo pro javascript, ele só pega um elemento. Segue o código abaixo.

PHP:

```
<?php

/* 
*
*essa lista será buscada de forma 
*dinâmica pelo banco de dados e
*gerado um array 
*
*/

$playlist = [
"e_amor.mp3", 
"dancando_lambada.mp3",
"lambada.mp3", 
"anjo_azul.mp3",
"acarta.mp3", 
"amor_de_julieta_e_romeu.mp3"
]; //lista de músicas

/*
*
*gera a nova playlist e envia o callback ao cliente
*
*/

shuffle($playlist); // gera a nova playlist

$new_playlist = []; //array vazio

foreach($playlist as $list){
  $new_playlist[] = $list;
}

echo json_encode(array('response' => $new_playlist));
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$().ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', "#shuffle", function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'data.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: true,

      success: function(e){
        var html;
        for(var i = 0; i < e.response.length; i++){
          console.log(e.response[i]); //Console funciona, só o html que não pega tudo.
          html = "<li>" + "<a href='"+ e.response[i] +"'>" + e.response[i] + "</a>" + "</li>";
        }
        $('.list').html(html);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Playlist</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="playlist">
      <ul class="list" style="list-style:none; float:left;">
        <li><a href="#">e_amor.mp3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">dancando_lambada.mp3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">lambada.mp3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">anjo_azul.mp3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">acarta.mp3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">amor_de_julieta_e_romeu.mp3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <button id="shuffle">Embaralhar playlist</button>
    <button>Salvar</button>
    <button>Deletar selecionadas</button>

    <!--SCRIPT-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Já tentei colocar o `$('.list').html(html);` dentro do laço de repetição;

Comment: Em vêz de `html =` testa com `html +=`

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado. Falta de atenção mesmo.

Comment: Ótimo. Coloquei uma resposta também, pois além de poder ser útil a outros sugiro usar o `reduce` nesses casos.

Comment: Irei marcar como melhor. Só que o sistema só vai liberar daqui 8 minutos. Obrigado.

Comment: so mais um detalhezinho, o `shuffle()` ja altera a variavel `$playlist`portanto nao tem necessidade de copiar o conteudo de `$playlist` para `$new_playlist`. Pode pular a etapa toda e colocar direto um `echo json_encode(array('response' => $playlist));`.

Comment: Eu tinha reparado isso, tanto que já fiz isso. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás a re-escrever a variável `html` a cada iteração desse loop.

Podes mudar para concatenação se usares `html +=` que é o mesmo que `html = html + "nova string"` ou podes usar `.reduce()`:

```
var html = e.response.reduce(function(str, entry) {
  return str + "<li><a href='" + entry + "'>" + entry + "</a></li>";
}, '');
$('.list').html(html);
```